# Installation problem sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

I should probably take this for a forum but figured someone here might know the answer.  I'm trying to install sql server 2008 on a home vista machine but it keeps telling 'Restart computer failed' everytime it does a check to make sure pre-reqs are met.  I've restarted my computer and even uinstalled/installed .net 3.5 sp1.
only thread i found about this was: http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/showpost.aspx?postid=3656807&siteid=1&sb=0&d=1&at=7&ft=11&tf=0&pageid=1

the last post on that forum states that there is a way to 'forcefully' (using command prompt) there is a way to bypass the reboot check.

does anyone know what commands can be used to bypass the rebook check??

Comment: Retagged "sql" & "server" & "2008" to the popular tags "sqlserver" & "sqlserver2008".  I don't think the tags "server" or "2008" were going to do much good here, and this isn't about Structured Query Language.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/78831/rule-restart-computer-failed-when-installing-sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found this here:
http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3762432&SiteID=1

"You can open Regedit, and modify this key"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager"  and delete any value in "PendingFileRenameOperations""

Comment: Also, note that in some case rather than there being a key at KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager there can also be a corrupted value with the same name at the same place.

Comment: Note: this is NOT a folder under the Session Manager folder, even though you will see more folders under it.  This is a setting.  So just click on Session Manager and look in the settings pane.

Comment: KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager has no folder called "PendingFileRenameOperations"". Only "FileRenameOperations" is present

Answer (score 14):

An easiest solution is installing by command line ignoring this verification:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck
```

Comment: Fixed for SQL 2014 as well.

Answer (score 7):

To skip reboot/restart check from the command line, use /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck

For more details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also try removing reboot keys under:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Source: https://forums.microsoft.com/TechNet/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3745175&SiteID=17

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the keys (like me), try this:

1. find the directory where setup.exe is unpacked
2. start cmd.exe and navigate to that directory
3. start install from command line:

   setup.exe /ACTION=install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQL2008 /SQLSVCACCOUNT=”NT Authority\System” /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=”yourPcName\yourUserName” /AGTSVCACCOUNT=”NT Authority\System” /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=”yourSqlPassword” /SQLTEMPDBDIR=”C:\SQL2008\TempDB\” /SQLUSERDBDIR=”C:\SQL2008\SQLData\” /SQLUSERDBLOGDIR=”C:\SQL2008\SQLLog\” /SkipRules=VSShellInstalledRule RebootRequiredCheck

Before executing pay attention to some parts of the code above:

```
INSTANCENAME=SQL2008
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=”yourPcName\yourUserName”
/SAPWD=”yourSqlPassword” 
/SQLTEMPDBDIR=”C:\SQL2008\TempDB\\” 
/SQLUSERDBDIR=”C:\SQL2008\SQLData\\” 
/SQLUSERDBLOGDIR=”C:\SQL2008\SQLLog\\”
```

If you couldn't find out tags above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(SQL.100).aspx#Install